# How can I record synthesizer music to iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, network

I have an iPad Air 2 and I just bought Loopy HD.

I also have a Roland synthesizer with MIDI output. Is there a MIDI to lightning cable?

I want to play something on my synth and add it to Loopy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the synth you have is core MIDI compatible. You may use a [Apple iPad Camera Connection Kit](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter?fnode=91&rdt=redirectionFromProductPage) or the [Apple USB 3 Camera Connection Kit](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK0W2AM/A/lightning-to-usb-3-camera-adapter?fnode=91&rdt=redirectionFromProductPage) if it requires a bit of power output.

Other alternatives to just straight up USB for non-core MIDI products (products that require drivers) include [iRig](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=mobile) accessories, or [plugKEY](http://www.korg.com/us/products/computergear/plugkey/).

You will need [this cable](https://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA91R3NY6040&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCAMKPL-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwordsCAMKPL-PC-_-pla-_-Home+Gadgets-_-9SIA91R3NY6040&gclid=CO_M6brOwtMCFQwwaQodfwUJKQ) to make it work.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks! I have a Roland E-38. It doesn't have any USB outputs though... you can look it up to see what I mean.

Comment: Added a link to an MIDI to USB output... Checked the Manufacturer's docs, and it should work...

Comment: Could this work? Basically I would do MIDI to Lightning directly. http://www.guitarcenter.com/IK-Multimedia/iRig-MIDI-2-1403532937623.gc